# Complex relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, algorithm, eloquent

I have one interesting problem in Laravel database.
There are 5 tables, A, AB, B, BC, C.
A and B have many to many relation through AB table.
B and C have many to many relation through BC table.
From a record in A table, get all related records in B table.
And then try to get records in C that contains all the results obtained above.
So the process to do this is 1->many-many.
How can I do this with one query?

I have no idea how to do this. Not allowed to use loop function. Only with one query.

Comment: You tagged this with eloquent. The eloquent way of doing this is using relationships and so will necessarily require more than 1 query (i.e. 1 query to get A, 1 query to get all related B and 1 more query to get all related C). Compared to a JOIN this usually takes the same time but requires less data to be transferred. However compared to not using eloquent this is slower because each model needs to be instantiated which has some overhead over using an `stdClass`. Your requirements are not that clear so I will assume eloquent might not actually be appropriate for you at all.

Comment: You can also check if [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package can help you.

Comment: Consider updating your question to include the applicable metadata of the tables being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join method multiple times to join the necessary tables and apply the required conditions.

```
$recordId = 1; // The ID of the record in the A table

$results = DB::table('A')
    ->join('AB', 'A.id', '=', 'AB.A_id')
    ->join('B', 'B.id', '=', 'AB.B_id')
    ->join('BC', 'B.id', '=', 'BC.B_id')
    ->join('C', 'C.id', '=', 'BC.C_id')
    ->where('A.id', $recordId)
    ->get(['C.*']);
```

Comment: Hello, Karl. Thank you very much for your instant answering.
Your answer helped me a lot.
And I would like to ask you, If you are not busy, could you tell me how I can do this using Eloquent?

Comment: @GEP1 you are using Eloquent, what you want is an Eloquent relationship. You can get a relation of a relation by [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) but you cannot get a value/model from a relation of a relation (x3+, not with normal relationships, you will have to define some stuff using eloquent like a `where` or similar but not directly by using `belongsToMany` or anything like that)

Comment: @Karl Hill It will not going to better to define this relations in the model classes?

Comment: One question, there are many same records in the result. B records that C has must contain all the B records that A have. Then is the obtained result right?